# Find an algorithm for quickly computing results to a given equation

Tags: algorithm, math

There is an equation:

`280a + 80b + 75c + 50d + 25e - 30f - 42g = R`

- `a, b, c, d, e, f, g` - those are *modifiers*. They're strictly positive integer values.
- `R` - this is a *solution range*, the equation is valid as long as the result of its left side falls into that range.

---

The goal is:

- For each possible ***subset of the variable set*** find the smallest sum of ***modifiers*** values such that the result of the left side of the equation is within given ***solution range***.

Subsets are defined by inclusion of *modifiers*. I.e., *modifier* can either `== 0` or `> 0`.
For example:

- `b, c, d, e, f, g == 0` and `a > 0` is 1st subset
- `a, c, d, e, f, g == 0` and `b > 0` is 2nd subset
- `c, d, e, f, g == 0` and `a, b > 0` is 3rd subset
- etc...

Basically it's like counting in binary. Ergo there's a total of 128 subsets (technically 127 since a subset where all modifiers `== 0` isn't needed as a solution).

Note: I know that `e` can replace `c, d` modifiers as both of these are divisible by it, but I still need those as separate modifiers for the sake of unique permutations.

Basically, the ***solution range*** is the input and the result should be a ***list of all valid subsets with the smallest sum of modifiers***

Here's an example of a valid result:

- Let the range we input be from -2 to -2

Here's a list of smallest solutions for a couple different subsets (not all possible) with just `b, c, d, e, f, g` modifiers: https://imgur.com/a/ZlWeAlq (permutation == subset, I didn't use the correct terminology at the time).

Plugging these values in the equation will result in `-2` on every subset (assume `a` modifier is 0, I didn't include it in my first solver).

---

I made a quick bruteforce solution in C# with a parallel loop just going over all possible values (within boundaries) until it finds all solutions, but it's painfully slow.

A couple algorithms I have considered:

1. Breadth-first search:

   - Add 1 of each *modifier* and check if any individual "node" is a solution. Then add 1 of each *modifier* to each previous node and see if any of the new nodes are solutions.

     1. I'll have to somehow optimize it to not check the same path multiple times since adding 2 *modifiers* in different order will lead to the same node
     2. This grows really fast in terms of memory, so I'll have to limit it to some range of values within which I allow this "branching", and then I'll only allow addition of identical *modifiers* until that "branching range" is close enough to the *solution range*. Something like:

        - if a *solution range* is smth like 500-550, I'll only allow *modifiers* with positive coefficients to be added to itself until the value on each node is within 100 of the *solution range*
2. Simplify an arbitrary working answer:

   - Calculate the minimum difference you can create given the selected modifier set
   - Calculate how many minimum differences added together it takes to get into a *solution range* which can give a large number of modifiers being used but its a working answer
   - Use a table to quickly simplify/neutralize the modifiers with each other until you get the minimum possible
3. Bruteforce, but with even more optimization:

   - I could add the same range check to a bruteforce algorithm so that it only tries every combination within a given range, as well as remove some unnecessary repetitions (my current solution sucks quite hard)

Another hopefully decent optimization I can think of right off the bat is to remove impossible subsets for a given range at the very start.

For example, if a range is positive, then subsets where only `f`, only `g` or only `f, g` *modifiers* are `> 0` will never be a valid answer since both of these have negative coefficients (can't ever reach a positive range by adding negative values).

---

So the essence of my question is:

- Which algorithm, either from the ones that I thought of or from other existing algorithms that I didn't think of, would be able to quickly and efficiently solve this problem?
- How would a basic implementation of such algorithm look like?

I have yet to try to implement any of these since I'm not sure whether they will be good at all and if there are any existing algorithms that would be much better than any of the things I could think of. My bruteforce solution still exists and, if needed, I can link it. It is terribly slow tho and definitely not worth comparison in its current form.

Comment: @Enigmativity If there's a website in Stack Exchange community that is more fitting for this question, feel free to let me know. I'm not asking you to write me a whole program, I'm asking about a better algorithm and its basic implementation. What is so unfitting in my question that it requires immediate closing?

Comment: It's certainly not a C# programming issue. There is a Computer Science Stack Exchange site. I have no idea about their posting guidelines

Comment: @Flydog57 I added C# for a lack of a better tag, but I could remove it since there is #algorithm tag now. If the question doesn't get answered here tho, I will see if Computer Science Stack Exchange works, thanks! 
Also C# is my main language and the one that I wrote my initial solution in, so there's a bit of a bias from my side.

Comment: Perhaps https://or.stackexchange.com would be better suited than https://cs.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think the problem as is is well stated. What does 'find the smallest positive integer solution' mean when you have 7 non-negative integers? What about R? Are you trying to minimise that too?

Comment: @Noby try your problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @SimonGoater The goal is to find the smallest combination of positive integer values of *modifiers* for each *permutation* of those modifiers such that the answer to the result of the left side of the equation lies within some *range* `R`. The range can be chosen freely.

Comment: For example, say the range is -2 to -2, then here's an example of a list of smallest solutions for different permutations with just `b, c, d, e, f, g` modifiers (those are not all the permutations, but just a couple as an example): https://imgur.com/a/ZlWeAlq . And if you try to plug these values in the equation, the result will indeed be -2 on every permutation (assume `a` modifier is `0`).

Comment: The question probably seems to be more on the math side, rather than programming. However, the goal is not to find an algorithm that *can* solve the problem, the goal is to find an algorithm that can *quickly* solve the problem. I guess StackOverflow isn't the best place to ask so I'll probably try to ask the same question on https://or.stackexchange.com/ as well

Comment: I second Simon's question: It isn't clear what you mean by "smallest". And it also isn't clear if the range is part of the input or of the solution (it seems like it would be part of the input, but then you said it "can be chosen freely").

Comment: just curious.. OP question title is "Find smallest positive integer.. ", but in the question is ".. fast calculator .. and how should I implement it?" IS the question.. mind to clarify?

Comment: @interjay the range is the only input. By "chosen freely" I mean you can enter whatever range you want, but if I can rewrite it in a better way, feel free to let me know and I'll edit the post

Comment: You aren't talking about *permutations* at all so much as subsets of the variable set. If it was permutations then the number of possible solutions would be a factorial rather than a power of 2.

Comment: @Noby What you called "Dijkstra algorithm" is, as far as I can see, a solution. Except it is called BFS and you need to avoid visiting the same value twice, path doesn't matter.

Comment: fwiw + (really) imho : OP already have the algo & code ready, just need to verify the timings via standardized benchmark. then.. 2 things need to do. [1] update hte question by (a) chg the title to "how to make these___run faster. "as title & (b) insert ur written codes 4all the shared algo (including the original brute one) in the question.  [2] share some sample timing results of ur own (or maybe online.. eg  https://tio.run ), shared how much had u tried to optimize ur hardware/setup/'R' value range. btw.. if u r looking for shorter codes u should look into [codegolf.se] or similar sites.

Comment: @p._phidot_ doesn't the last paragraph of the question state the opposite?

Comment: That is.. what I meant (in my 1st comment). || If.. the question ask about "is there any other algo for __ ?" then the question is better suited to [math.se] , but if.. to ask "which of these algo is faster?" the just frame the benchmark requirements (eg standadized testDataSet, same code run differentMachine/cloud, or same docker run on different machine) and any constrain (RAM/storage/interface) if applicable.

Comment: @p._phidot_ the last paragraph is just a list of different solutions / optimization ideas I could think of. The essence of the question is: "Which algorithm, either from the ones that I thought of or from other existing algorithms that I didn't think of, would be able to quickly and efficiently solve this problem". Although I do realize that some standardized benchmarking would be necessary, I'm still looking for other possible algorithms before comparing them to the ones I could think of. Maybe there is an optimal solution to such problem that I just didn't find. That's what I wanna know

Comment: @Noby I've implemented the BFS solution and it takes a little more than 1 second to process 10000 queries on `R` (for all masks): `-5000 <= R <= 5000`. What are the actual limits you need to solve this problem for, what performance mark do you need to achieve?

Comment: @maxplus Does it mean you calculated every solution for each individual value from -5000 to 5000? Because if that's so, then it is impressive. I don't have any *specific* range I need to solve it for. I need it to quickly calculate solution for any given range somewhere within -50000 and 50000. It can be an arbitrarily small range, like from -50000 to -49999. The range is the *input*. All the different "permutations" each of which will make the result of the left side of the equation fall within that range is the *output*

Comment: @Noby Yes, for each value for each subset. For wider ranges than length 1 this solution should work even faster. For `45000 <= R <= 50000` it takes ~15 seconds. If your use case allows precalculating a large array and using it to solve arbitrary queries, time per query can be improved a lot and make R ~ 10^7 available, but that would be a different implementation. Optimal implementation will also depend on how wide a range can be: there is an approach that works in logarithmic time in the length of the range, but it increases memory requirement even further and makes precalculation slower.

Comment: So I suggest you describe your requirements in as much detail as you can, otherwise you might get not the best fit solution/get an unnecessarily complicated solution that you won't be willing to reimplement in C# :) (I'll write it in C++)

Comment: @maxplus Yeah, I'll try to rewrite my question to some degree and see if I can figure out a better phrasing for it. Thanks!

Comment: @maxplus I edited the question quite a bit. Hopefully it is clearer now. Feel free to provide feedback on how I could improve it further

Comment: Once you have a small solution (c=d=1, g=3), you need to check few combinations of coefficients.

Comment: @Noby you haven't addressed any of the issues I brought up in my comment. There must be a specific usage pattern a solution should be optimized for with specific limits. 1) Absolute value of `R`. Up to 50000? Fine. 2) Whether precomputation is allowed or every query should be solved from scratch. 3) Range length. An efficient solution that precomputes for wide ranges, say >100 length, is different from an efficient solution for small ranges. The former uses a custom binary tree/a segment tree that might be hard for someone unfamiliar to understand and reimplement.

Comment: 4) Specific runtime limits. 4.1) how much memory can be used. If 50000 is indeed the maximum `R`, this probably doesn't matter, memory usage will be low in any case. 4.2) The nature of execution time limit. I can think of two patterns: query latency minimization (an unlimited stream of random queries with repetitions will be submitted and each should be processed as fast as possible, optimizing worst case), then some acceptable bound on latency, say 1 millisecond, should exist;

Comment: batched computations (part of a larger algorithm generating a certain pattern and amount of queries, optimizing average case), then the total amount of work should be known and an acceptable bound on processing time should exist, like waiting 10 minutes for a roughly specified set of queries is ok

Comment: @maxplus 1) Upper bound at 50000 and lower bound at -50000 is fine. 2) Some amount precomputation is fine, but I wouldn't want a huge list of precomputed solutions. At most it could be a list of smallest differences you can create with certain subsets of modifiers or smth like that (if that helps the solution). 3) Range length should be anything in-between 1 and 100. I also need it to be able to solve for each individual value in some range, but assuming it can calculate a solution for a range length 1 fast enough, it shouldn't be an issue to implement.

Comment: 4) Can't say there are any specific limits on runtime / memory usage. My bruteforce approach solves for a range of 1 in like a whole 10 seconds, I want to take this time down to ms ideally (relative to my hardware at least). CPU usage already spikes to 95% with the current solution so I think it's fine to use as much memory / computational power as it can (assuming it doesn't damage the PC by doing so). I could also add all those points to the actual post if you think it's gonna be helpful

Comment: @Noby does my post answer your question?

Comment: @maxplus Sorry, I'm a bit busy atm, but I appreciate your help and will come to test your answer in the near future. Btw, I skimmed through the code and was wondering whether you considered removing impossible subsets in advance? Like how if the range is strictly > 0, then subsets that only include negative modifiers will never have a solution, so they can be removed. I'm wondering whether that would be a meaningful performance boost

Comment: @Noby Yes, this optimization is implemented in the first example (`pos`, `neg` variables). I haven't benchmarked it separately but it should reduce the number of operations by 10-20%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main idea of my solution is simple BFS. For a given subset you start with an initial configuration of 0-1 modifiers having an associated value (sum on the left hand side of your equation) and cost (sum of modifiers). In each step the cheapest configuration is extracted from a queue and each of its neighbors (adjacent by increasing a single modifier) is considered.

A few necessary observations. If there are several configurations producing the same value, only one of those with the minimum cost needs to be considered, so each distinct value will be placed in a queue at most once. We don't have to add a negative modifier if we are below target range and we don't have to add a positive modifier if we are above, so search space is trivially bounded.

This gives a solution that constructs minimum cost configuration for a given range `R = [from, to]` and a mask in `O(max(|from|, |to|))` memory and time. Note that while solving for any given range we will encounter many solutions for others queries and it is wasteful to discard them.

---

Implementation example #1, C++, solving each query from scratch:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

constexpr int N = 7;

// this corresponds to subset ordering on the screenshot
constexpr std::array<int, N> coef{-42, 75, -30, 80, 25, 50, 280};

struct Solution {
  int lhs;
  std::array<int, N> mods;
};

Solution solve(int mask, int l, int r) {
  Solution init{};
  int low = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), high = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
  // int g = 0, neg = 0, pos = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (mask & 1 << i) {
    // g = std::gcd(g, coef[i]);
    // neg += coef[i] < 0;
    // pos += coef[i] > 0;
    init.lhs += coef[i];
    init.mods[i] = 1;
    low = std::min(low, r + 1 + coef[i]);
    high = std::max(high, l - 1 + coef[i]);
  }
  if (l <= init.lhs && init.lhs <= r) {
    return init;
  }
  // if (g == 0 || r - (r % g + g) % g < l || l > 0 && pos == 0 || r < 0 && neg == 0) {
  //   return {l - 1, {}};
  // }
  low = std::min(low, init.lhs);
  high = std::max(high, init.lhs);
  std::queue<int> q;
  q.push(init.lhs - low);
  std::vector<int8_t> last_move(high - low + 1);
  last_move[init.lhs - low] = -1;
  int restore_from = 0;
  l -= low, r -= low;
  while (!q.empty()) {
    int cur_val = q.front();
    q.pop();
    // #pragma GCC unroll 7
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (mask & 1 << i) {
      if (coef[i] < 0? cur_val < l: cur_val > r) {
        continue;
      }
      int next_val = cur_val + coef[i];
      if (last_move[next_val]) {
        continue;
      }
      last_move[next_val] = i + 1;
      if (l <= next_val && next_val <= r) {
        restore_from = next_val;
        q = {};
        break;
      }
      q.push(next_val);
    }
  }
  if (l > restore_from || restore_from > r) {
    return {l + low - 1, {}};
  }
  init.lhs = restore_from + low;
  while (last_move[restore_from] != -1) {
    ++init.mods[last_move[restore_from] - 1];
    restore_from -= coef[last_move[restore_from] - 1];
  }
  return init;
}

int main() {
  int64_t sum = 0;
  for (int R = -5000; R <= 5000; ++R) {
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << N; ++mask) if (auto res = solve(mask, R, R); res.lhs == R) {
      sum += std::accumulate(res.mods.begin(), res.mods.end(), 0);

      // this prints unit range, subset, solution cost and solution itself
      // std::cout << '=' << R << " #" << mask + 1 << ": " << std::accumulate(res.mods.begin(), res.mods.end(), 0) << '\n';
      // for (auto x: res.mods) {
      //   std::cout << ' ' << +x;
      // }
      // std::cout << '\n';
    }
  }
  std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Commented lines of code inside `solve` are minor optimizations that improve running time ~twice if uncommented. This is not the most optimized implementation of this approach, because the other somewhat faster version I have is less readable and AFAIK impossible to translate to C#. Without them this code runs on my current machine in ~6s, solving for each unit range from -5000 to 5000 independently.

---

Implementation example #2, C++, precomputing minimum cost for each unit range (`from == to`):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <numeric>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

constexpr int N = 7;

// this corresponds to subset ordering on the screenshot in the question
constexpr std::array<int, N> coef{-42, 75, -30, 80, 25, 50, 280};

struct Solution {
  int lhs;
  std::array<int, N> mods;
};

class Precalc {
public:
  Precalc(int min_R, int max_R)
      : min_R{min_R},
        max_R{max_R},
        low_val{std::min({min_R, 0, min_R + 1 + *std::min_element(coef.begin(), coef.end())})},
        high_val{std::max({max_R, 0, max_R - 1 + *std::max_element(coef.begin(), coef.end())})},
        last_move{},
        cost{} {
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << N; ++mask) {
      last_move[mask].resize(high_val - low_val + 1);
      cost[mask].resize(high_val - low_val + 1);
      do_precalc(mask);
    }
  }

  Solution get_solution(int mask, int from, int to) const {
    assert(min_R <= from && from <= to && to <= max_R);
    int best_cost = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    int best_value = 0;
    for (int val = from; val <= to; ++val) {
      if (last_move[mask][val - low_val] != 0 && best_cost > cost[mask][val - low_val]) {
        best_cost = cost[mask][val - low_val];
        best_value = val;
      }
    }
    if (best_cost == std::numeric_limits<int>::max()) {
      return {from - 1, {}};
    }
    Solution res{best_value, {}};
    int restore_from = best_value;
    while (last_move[mask][restore_from - low_val] != -1) {
      ++res.mods[last_move[mask][restore_from - low_val] - 1];
      restore_from -= coef[last_move[mask][restore_from - low_val] - 1];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (mask & 1 << i) {
      ++res.mods[i];
    }
    return res;
  }

private:
  void do_precalc(int mask) {
    int init = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (mask & 1 << i) {
      init += coef[i];
    }
    if (low_val > init || init > high_val) {
      return;
    }
    std::queue<int> q;
    q.push(init);
    last_move[mask][init - low_val] = -1;
    while (!q.empty()) {
      int cur_val = q.front();
      q.pop();
      for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) if (mask & 1 << i) {
        int next_val = cur_val + coef[i];
        if (low_val > next_val || next_val > high_val || last_move[mask][next_val - low_val] != 0) {
          continue;
        }
        last_move[mask][next_val - low_val] = i + 1;
        cost[mask][next_val - low_val] = cost[mask][cur_val - low_val] + 1;
        q.push(next_val);
      }
    }
  }

  int min_R, max_R;
  int low_val, high_val;
  std::array<std::vector<int8_t>, 1 << N> last_move;
  std::array<std::vector<uint16_t>, 1 << N> cost;
};

int main() {
  int min_R = -50000, max_R = 50000;
  Precalc precalc{min_R, max_R};
  int64_t sum = 0;
  for (int R = min_R; R <= max_R; ++R) {
    for (int mask = 0; mask < 1 << N; ++mask) {
      if (auto res = precalc.get_solution(mask, R, R); res.lhs == R) {
        sum += std::accumulate(res.mods.begin(), res.mods.end(), 0);
      }
      int from = std::max(R - 50, min_R), to = std::min(R + 50, max_R);
      if (auto res = precalc.get_solution(mask, from, to); res.lhs >= from) {
        assert(res.lhs <= to);
        sum += std::accumulate(res.mods.begin(), res.mods.end(), 0);
      }
    }
  }
  std::cout << sum << '\n';
}
```

Precomputation itself takes less than a second and occupies ~37 megabytes. The whole program, solving for 200002 ranges, half of them length 1 and half — length 101, takes 40s.

Note that this implementation is still quite silly. We still take `O(max(|from|, |to|))` time to restore a configuration, although with much better constant factor. It is trivial to memoize full configurations instead of merely the cost and the last move and answer each query in `O(to - from)`, but this will increase memory footprint ~6 times and contradicts one of the requirements, being a "list of precomputed solutions". If something like that is desired, only a part of configurations could be memoized instead, for example all (optimal) configurations with costs divisible by 16, stored in a hash table.